# What kind of nail do I use to hang a 10kg mirror?

Tags: hanging, mirror

I recently purchased a mirror that weighs 10 kg and has a hanging attachment in the centre that looks like the attached image.

Are there special shape of hooks used for these kinds of hanging attachments?

[image]

Comment: You're not exactly asking the right question. Almost _any_ nail or screw that fits the slot will work. Of much greater concern is _what's holding up the nail_. Can you revise to tell us about that?

Comment: I’ll be hanging the mirror on a drywall.

Comment: Ask me for a regular flat head nail and I will give you a 3 1/2 nail, which will work, but might be over kill.

Comment: Please **revise** to tell us about that. Take the [tour] to learn how this site works.

Comment: Or this? [What are some ways to appropriately hang things on a wall?](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/6144/what-are-some-ways-to-appropriately-hang-things-on-a-wall)

Comment: did you read the instlation instructions on the mirror?